# Iterator, Iterable java

Tags: java

Использовать типизированный класс ArrManager,
В котором находится инкапсулированный массив типа данных
Object[] и реализованны интерфейсы Iterable, Iterator.

Создать Класс который реализует итератор для перебора внутреннего 
массива объектов от начала до конца.

Этот итератр должен в конструкторе принимать позиции 
начала и конца перебора.

Если значение начала меньше нуля то в итераторе оно должно
заменятся на 0.

Если значение конца больше размера то оно заменяется на 
значение размера.

main :

```
public class Home_work_Iterator_Iterable {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       ArrManager<Integer> arm = new ArrManager<>(new Integer[]{1,2,3});

        System.out.println(arm.toString());


    }

}
```

Arrmanger class :

```
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 *
 * @author Pivar
 * @param <T>
 */
public class ArrManager<T> implements Iterator<T>, Iterable<T> {

    private Object[] data;
    private int size;

    public ArrManager() {
    }

    public Object[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public T get(int index) {
        if (index >= 0 && index < size) {
            return (T) data[index];
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ArrManager{" + "data=" + data + ", size=" + size + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

ArrmanagerIterator class:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 *
 * @author Pivar
 * @param <T>
 */
public class ArrManagerIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private int cursor;
    private ArrManager arm;
    private int cursor_Start;
    private int cursor_End;

    public ArrManagerIterator(ArrManager<T> arm, int cursor_Start, int cursor_End) {
        this.arm = arm;
        this.cursor_Start = (cursor_Start < 0) ? 0 : cursor_Start;
        this.cursor_End = (cursor_End > arm.getSize() - 1) ? arm.getSize() - 1 : cursor_End;
        this.cursor = this.cursor_Start;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (cursor >= cursor_Start && cursor <= cursor_End) {
            return true;
        }
        this.cursor = cursor_Start;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        return (T) arm.get(cursor++);
    }

}
```

У меня не получается вывести массив что бы проверить правильно ли по заданию. Да и вообщем нужна помощь, мне кажется что то я сделал не так =(

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы ваш метод `toString` работал как задумано, нужно в нём выводить все элементы внутреннего массива, который хранит данные, например, так:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        String arrayData = Arrays.toString(data);
        return "ArrManager{" + "data=" + arrayData + ", size=" + size + '}';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ArrManager<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    private final T[] data;

    public ArrManager(T[] t) {
        this.data = t;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ArrManager{" + "data=" + Arrays.toString(data) + ", size=" + data.length + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new ArrManagerIterator<>(0, data.length);
    }

    private class ArrManagerIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

        private final int cursorStart;
        private final int cursorEnd;
        private int cursor;

        public ArrManagerIterator(int cursorStart, int cursorEnd) {
            this.cursorStart = (cursorStart < 0) ? 0 : cursorStart;
            this.cursorEnd = (cursorEnd > data.length - 1) ? data.length - 1 : cursorEnd;
            this.cursor = this.cursorStart;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return cursor <= cursorEnd;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            return (T) data[cursor++];
        }

    }

}


public class Home_work_Iterator_Iterable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrManager<Integer> arm = new ArrManager<>(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3});

        Iterator<Integer> i = arm.iterator();

        while(i.hasNext()) System.out.println(i.next());

        System.out.println(arm.toString());

    }

}
```

Comment: не работает....(

Comment: Поменяйте cursor_Start на cursorStart и cursor_End на cursorEnd в конструкторе ArrManagerIterator

Comment: я менял ошибка Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at home_work_iterator_iterable.ArrManagerIterator.<init>(ArrManagerIterator.java:24)
 at home_work_iterator_iterable.ArrManager.iterator(ArrManager.java:31)
 at home_work_iterator_iterable.Home_work_Iterator_Iterable.main(Home_work_Iterator_Iterable.java:20)
Java Result: 1

Comment: исправил, попробуйте еще раз...

Comment: ок только есть другая проблема если значение начала меньше нуля то в итераторе оно должно заменятся на 0, а оно выводить просто минусовое число

Comment: кто оно? значение начала передается в конструкторе return new ArrManagerIterator<>(0, data.length); сецчас та 0, если поставит -5, то все равно все работает

Comment: да, но вместо -5 должно выводится 0

Comment: куда выводиться? - 5 никуда не выводится. оно передается в конструкторе и сразу подменяется на 0